# Cron expression for every hour and 30 minutes

Tags: cron

I have tried cron expression `30 * * * *`, but it runs starting of every hour.

Source: https://crontab.guru/every-hour-at-30-minutes

Please guide for correct expression.

Expected should be:

If First run at 2019-09-10 18:30:00
then at 2019-09-10 19:30:00
then at 2019-09-10 20:30:00
then at 2019-09-10 21:30:00
then at 2019-09-10 22:30:00

Comment: Looking at the example you gave...you need expression for every 1 hour?

Comment: your example is correct it works how you need, https://i.imgur.com/wuQgxoc.png

i think the question is not clear

Comment: you cron expression looks correct. as per the cron expression, it will run every hour at 30 minutes. The issue could be due to the timezone difference between the system where you are running this cron and other system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my observation I came to know that we are dealing with UTC,
So for India I kept 45 * * * * and now its executing 1.15, 2.15, 3.15

As India is UTC+5.30, so 30 * * * * will execute beginning of every hour.

UTC need to be taken care :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in a single cron expression, since the minutes will have to alternate between 0 and 30 depending on the iteration.

The two cron expressions you would need are:

```
0   0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21  * * * blah
30  1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * blah
```

Hope this helps.